# Bing map. Add icon points and existing names near the map disappear

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Add a pin to the bing map, and the place names where the map exists will disappear.   I wonder how to make the place names where the map exists not disappear.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZGua.png)

Add a pin to the existing place name of the bing map, and the existing place name text will not disappear or move the location

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.